# How to display rich text image (saved in Notes document) in XPages

Tags: image, xpages

Everyone keeps talking about opening the attachment.  IT'S NOT AN ATTACHMENT!  The image was pasted in a rich text field in Notes cocument.  When I view the properties of one these Notes documents with the image, (unfortunately I'm not able to paste images to this), there are internal fields created for this rich text field namely MIME_Version, and the name of the rich text field listed four (4) times as shown below:

```
Field Name: myImage
Data Type: MIME Part
Data Length: 141 bytes
Seq Num: 3
Dup Item ID: 1
Field Flags: SIGN SEAL 

"Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=_related 006391B688257C0D_="

This is a multipart message in MIME format.
"
___________________________________________________
Field Name: myImage
Data Type: MIME Part
Data Length: 150 bytes
Seq Num: 3
Dup Item ID: 2
Field Flags: SIGN SEAL 

"--=_related 006391B688257C0D_=
Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII"

<img src=cid:_2_0BCE1D8C0BCE1ACC006391B688257C0D>
"
____________________________________________________
Field Name: myImage
Data Type: MIME Part
Data Length: 14064 bytes
Seq Num: 3
Dup Item ID: 3
Field Flags: SIGN SEAL 

"--=_related 006391B688257C0D_=
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-ID: <_2_0BCE1D8C0BCE1ACC006391B688257C0D>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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 ..."

_________________________________________________
Field Name: myImage
Data Type: MIME Part
Data Length: 54 bytes
Seq Num: 3
Dup Item ID: 4
Field Flags: SIGN SEAL 

"--=_related 006391B688257C0D_=--
"
```

Can someone please let me know how to display this image saved in a Notes document, in Xpages. What type of XPages control should be used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple data binding to bind to a Rich Text field in the current document.

In my case binding to document1 a field called OverviewPicsChildparts which contains a pasted image works fine.

However I am trying to display a pasted image into a repeat control whose source is a DocumentCollection of response documents to document1 which is not as straight forward it seems.

However I solved this by adding this code...

```
<xp:this.data>                  
  <xp:dominoDocument var="doc"
      action="openDocument"
      documentId="#{javascript:AllResponseDocs.getNoteID()}"            ignoreRequestParams="true">
  </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Into a panel inside the repeat control and then was able to use Simple Data Binding binding to doc the field I wanted like this...

```
<xp:inputRichText 
  id="inputRichText1" 
  value="#{doc.ProPicture}" 
  readonly="true"
  style="width:198.0px;height:141.0px">
</xp:inputRichText>
```

it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  My richtext field ONLY has an image and as you said it's just a matter of using simple data binding which I've done but to no avail.  <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"
     style="width:231.0px;height:83.0px"
     value="#{document1.viewFrom18thImage}">
    </xp:inputRichText>

Answer (score 0):

As Steve said, to display RichText data, you need the RichText control. Quite simple.

If the RichText data contains an image AND other data, like text or tables, things are different and much more complicated. In that case you need the NotesMIME classes to get the HTML representation of the RichText data, parse it, extract references to the image you want, then run through all MIME items to find the one holding the image data.

So in a nutshell: when the RichText contains the image alone, it's easy and Steve gave a good example. Otherwise it's complicated.